# Windows 10 freeze after SSD installation

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, freeze

After installing an SSD in my computer (with Windows 10), leaving the old HDD for storage, I'm having random freezes: The pointer is still moving, and the first seconds I can still select things, but quickly everything becomes unresponsibe, programs, task bar... The only way to shutdown the computer is by hold the power button.

After reboot the computer, right after the motherboard start screen, a black screen appears with the message:

```
    Reboot and Select proper Boot device
    or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key...
```

When this happens, the only way to make Windows boot properly is to open the case, disconnect the SSD (both data and power wires) and connect it again.

It happens randomly, and it's so annoying. What could be the problem?
I don't know what to attach, so tell me whatever thing you need!

My setup is:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P Rev
- CPU: AMD FX-8350
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Savage DDR3 1866 PC3-14900 8GB CL9
- SSD: Crucial BX300 240 GB
- HDD: Seagate Desktop 7200.14 1TB SATA3
- GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 960 OC WindForce 4GB DDR5
- PSU: EVGA supernova g2 650w

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it happen if you boot off a Linux LiveCD? Have you tried booting into safe mode? Are there any error messages in the event log?

Comment: I didn't tried LiveCD or safe mode because this issue happens totally randomly, maybe one time per week, month or two times in an hour. There are some errors on the event log, but right now I don't remember which ones, I'll post it later when I arrive home. Thanks!